# Searching mysql for specific character inside serialize data

Tags: mysql, regex, serialization

I have these data store in MySQL [and] I'm try[ing] to return only records/rows (data) containing the [character] "C".

```
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"C";}
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"A";i:1;s:1:"C";}
a:3:{i:0;s:1:"A";i:1;s:1:"C";i:2;s:1:"F";}
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"C";}
```

I have tried;

```
SELECT return_id,customerReason FROM `cscart_zul_return` WHERE customerReason REGEXP 'C'
```

it end up return all row instead.

Can someone help me on how to achieve this.

Comment: What would be an example of *'...return only data containing "C"'*?

Comment: Does `"C"` exist in all rows? Also are we looking at only the record set for `customerReason`?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be much easier to use a normal like query:

```
SELECT return_id, customerReason
FROM cscart_zul_return
WHERE customerReason LIKE '%"C"%'
```